# Android Best Practice: Dynamically adding buttons to a ViewPager or Pre-Instantiating Them?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

So I have a question about best practice for dynamically creating and sizing buttons within a ViewPager, based on a changing external state.

Essentially, I have a scrolling view and I want my ViewPager to contain a number of buttons of a specific size and count depending on what part of the scrolling view is currently visible.

My question is about deciding the best implementation of this feature, I see two options: would it be simpler to

1. Constantly create and scale new buttons whenever the scrolling view moves
2. Make the viewpager itself contain a scrollview and fill it with all of the pre-scaled buttons on app startup. Then, whenever the user scrolls the main scrollview the viewpager's scrollview (which contains the buttons) will scale programatically

[image: ViewPager is Green, Main ScrollView is Red]

Any ideas on which would be the simpler and more robust system?

Comment: Not much of an answer but I will leave a comment for ya! Basically you can do it either way, both aren't to difficult to accomplish, however I would probably go the dynamic route because it will always scale correctly. Doing a set amount will only work until devices become larger, or if you are targeting tablets or tvs then it will start to become extremely messy in the xml file for the layout. Dynamically adding also gives you far more control and saves time later on, you can simply change a number and have 100 more then going through and manually adding even 10. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you submit this as an answer I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer but I will leave a comment for ya! Basically you can do it either way, both aren't to difficult to accomplish, however I would probably go the dynamic route because it will always scale correctly. Doing a set amount will only work until devices become larger, or if you are targeting tablets or tvs then it will start to become extremely messy in the xml file for the layout. Dynamically adding also gives you far more control and saves time later on, you can simply change a number and have 100 more then going through and manually adding even 10. Hope this helps!